# Post appearing in unknown circumstances

Tags: feature-request, migrated-questions

I've just noticed [this old meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298380/dennis-ritchie-goes-into-the-night-without-a-quote-on-stack-overflow) in the new questions feed:

[image]

It has no indication of *what* happened 5 hours ago, and looking through the post there are no edits, no new comments, no new answers etc.

What happened?

Edit:

Just noticed the large "Migrated from meta.stackexchange.com 5 hours ago" banner on the question...!

Perhaps then this is a feature request that that information is presented in the question list, eg:

[image]

Comment: I have seen mention of server-side caching that can cause information from appearing too late, this is perhaps another victim?